# Intersection of integer sets

Tags: algorithms, diophantine-equations, linear-diophantine-equations

This is probably a trivial question for mathematicians but I am not seeing how to approach the following problem:

Imagine two sets defined by:

```
set1 = (x: x<stop1 and x = start1, ..., start1+n*step1, ...; n element of set of integers)
set2 = (x: x<stop2 and x = start2, ..., start2+m*step2, ...; m element of set of integers)
```

Where:

- all variables are integers
- step != 0

Example of what I mean by this:

```
for start = 3, stop = 20, step = 5:
set =  [3, 8, 13, 18]
```

I am looking for:

- whether the two sets intersect
- what start, stop, step are for the intersection set

Comment: What are $m$ and $n$?

Comment: @ToddWilcox m and n are integer. I added an example of what I mean with this notation to the question.

Comment: @Max I added a Ruby implementation to my answer. Have a look at the excerpt from the log to better understand how it works.

Answer (score 2):

**Mathematical Model:**

You could model the sets $S_1$ and $S_2$ like this
\begin{align}
I_1 &= [a_1, b_1) \quad (a_1, b_1 \in \mathbb{N})\\
I_2 &= [a_2, b_2) \quad (a_2, b_2 \in \mathbb{N}) \\
Z_1 &= \{ x = a_1 + n \Delta x_1 \mid n \in \mathbb{Z} \} \quad (\Delta x_1 \in \mathbb{N}) \\
Z_2 &= \{ x = a_2 + m \Delta x_2 \mid m \in \mathbb{Z} \} \quad (\Delta x_2 \in \mathbb{N}) \\
S_1 &= Z_1 \cap I_1 \subseteq I_1 \\
S_2 &= Z_2 \cap I_2 \subseteq I_2 
\end{align}
Then for an element of the intersection $S_1 \cap S_2$ we have the condition
$$
a_1 + n \Delta x_1 = a_2 + m \Delta x_2 \iff \\
(\Delta x_1) n - (\Delta x_2) m = a_2 - a_1 \quad (*)
$$
This is a [linear Diophantine equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_equation#One_equation)
$$
a x + b y = c \quad (**)
$$
plus the limiting condition
$$
a_1 + n \Delta x_1 \in I_1 \cap I_2
$$
A linear Diophantine equation $(**)$ has either no or infinite many solutions.
It has solutions if $\gcd(a,b) \mid c$.

**Applying the Solution of the Diophantine Equation:**

Translating this to the case of equation $(*)$ we have the criterion
$$
\gcd(\Delta x_1, \Delta x_2) \mid (a_2 - a_1) \quad (\#)
$$
In the case of solutions, we can find a particular solution by using the [extended Euclidean algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm) to find integers $s$, $t$ with the property
$$
s \Delta x_1 + t \Delta x_2 = \gcd(\Delta x_1, \Delta x_2) \quad (\#\#)
$$
Then 
$$
(n_0, m_0) = 
\left(
\frac{a_2-a_1}{\gcd(\Delta x_1, \Delta x_2)} s,
-\frac{a_2-a_1}{\gcd(\Delta x_1, \Delta x_2)} t
\right)
$$
is a solution of equation $(*)$.
Then all solutions are 
$$
(n, m) = 
\left(
n_0 + k \frac{\Delta x_2}{\gcd(\Delta x_1, \Delta x_2)},
m_0 + k \frac{\Delta x_1}{\gcd(\Delta x_1, \Delta x_2)},
\right)
\quad 
(k \in \mathbb{Z})
$$

**Determining the Unbounded Intersection:**

So we can use equation $(\#)$ to find out, if the intersection can have solutions. If it can, then we use the $s$ obtained by $(\#\#)$ to
calculate $n_0$ and use the first components of the above equation to calculate all $n$
and all elements 
$$
x 
= 
a_1 + n \Delta x_1 
= 
a_1 + \left(
\frac{a_2-a_1}{\gcd(\Delta x_1, \Delta x_2)} s +
k \frac{\Delta x_2}{\gcd(\Delta x_1, \Delta x_2)}
\right) \Delta x_1
\quad 
(k \in \mathbb{Z}) \quad (+)
$$ 
of
the unbounded intersection $Z_1 \cap Z_2$.

These then have to be tested against the boundaries of $I_1$ and $I_2$ to determine $S_1 \cap S_2$.
$$
a_1 \le x < b_1 \wedge a_2 \le x < b_2
$$
So it might a good idea to look even before $(\#)$ at $I_1 \cap I_2$ first, where we need
$$
a_1 < b_2 \wedge a_2 < b_1 \quad (++)
$$
for a non-empty intersection $I_1\cap I_2$.

**Start, Stop and Step of the Intersection:**

From the above we take that the step of the intersection set is
$$
\frac{\Delta x_1 \Delta x_2}{\gcd(\Delta x_1, \Delta x_2)}
\quad (\$)
$$
Start is found via the smallest feasible $k$, let us call it $k_1$
such that
$$
\left(
a_i - a_1 - \frac{a_2-a_1}{\gcd(\Delta x_1, \Delta x_2)} s \Delta x_1
\right)\frac{\gcd(\Delta x_1, \Delta x_2)}{\Delta x_1\Delta x_2}
\le k
$$
thus
$$
k_1 = \max_{i \in \{1,2\}} 
\left\lceil
\left(
a_i - a_1 - \frac{a_2-a_1}{\gcd(\Delta x_1, \Delta x_2)} s \Delta x_1
\right)\frac{\gcd(\Delta x_1, \Delta x_2)}{\Delta x_1\Delta x_2}
\right\rceil
$$

The element $x$ just before stop is found via the largest feasible $k$, let us call it $k_2$
such that
$$
k < 
\left(
b_i - a_1 - \frac{a_2-a_1}{\gcd(\Delta x_1, \Delta x_2)} s \Delta x_1
\right)\frac{\gcd(\Delta x_1, \Delta x_2)}{\Delta x_1\Delta x_2}
$$
thus
$$
k_2 = \min_{i \in \{1,2\}} 
\left\lfloor
\left(
b_i - a_1 - \frac{a_2-a_1}{\gcd(\Delta x_1, \Delta x_2)} s \Delta x_1
\right)\frac{\gcd(\Delta x_1, \Delta x_2)}{\Delta x_1\Delta x_2}
\right\rfloor
$$
or one less if the argument of floor was already an integer.

Plugging the found $k_1$ and $k_2$ into equation $(+)$ then gives start and stop values of the intersection.

**Summary:**
We gave two criteria, equations $(\#)$ and $(++)$ to determine if there is a non-empty intersection at all.

We further listed the solution process which allows to determine all solutions enumerated by an integer parameter $k$ and gave conditions how to find the parameters $k_1$ for the smallest and $k_2$ for the largest feasible solution, which can be used via equation $(+)$ to get start and stop values.

We also listed the step value of the intersection, see equation $(\$)$.

The method looks complicated, but has the big advantage of being fast, the sizes of the sets do not really matter, so I would consider it $O(1)$.

**Implementation:**

I implemented a sample program in Ruby, to find out if this works as planned. You can find the source code [here](https://gist.github.com/fac8ad3e942fc9565727).

I am happy to not have to correct the above formulas.

The biggest bug I was running into during implementation was not using floating point arithmetics for the calculation of $k_1$ and $k_2$. The rest only needs integer arithmetics.

Testing went against a brute force implementation of the set intersection.

Over one million random test cases passed, so I think it mostly works. See an excerpt from a log [here](https://gist.github.com/7f906ca4009f0361a741).

The output should help to understand this approach.

Comment: Thank you so much! It seems the problem is not quite as trivial as I first thought. It is going to take me a bit of time to digest your answer...

Comment: You write "solutions, we can find a particular solution by using the extended Euclidean algorithm to find integers s, t with the property ..." Why do the solutions satisfy this property? I am surprised since the offsets a1 and a2 do not seem to come into play.

Comment: The solutions of finding working  $n$ and $m$ show up after that, and involve the difference of $a_1$ and $a_2$.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you are considering the sets

$$A= \{x| x= a+n*s_A, \space n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$$
and
$$B= \{x| x= b+n*s_B, \space m\in\mathbb{Z}\}$$

with the given boundaries (in other words intersected with $[start, stop]$).

To solve $A\cap B$, you need to solve the diophantine equation

$$s_A*n - s_B*m = b-a$$

See for example here how this can be done: [Linear Diophantine Equation](http://www.millersville.edu/~bikenaga/number-theory/linear-diophantine/linear-diophantine.html)
Then take every $a+n*s_A$, for the $n$'s that are in a solution of the diophantine equation. Lastly intersect with the interval. Of course the way to actually do this is to start with the first non-negative $n$ and go on until $a+n*s_A$ becomes larger than the smaller of the boundaries.